# Create a rapidly varying frequency ckt with 555 timer

Tags: 555

I'd like to create a rapidly varying, and repeating, frequency ckt (with a 555 timer if possible), in the audio range, that will drive points of constructive interference up the inside of a tube, by changing the wavelength, from the ckt and speaker at one end.

How would I do this? TIA.

Comment: Is this what is often called, in English, a ***chirp***? (These can be up-chirps or down-chirps, which is another question I may have.)

Comment: Varying , repeating frequency, i.e. frequency modulation?

Answer (score 0):

Two cascaded 555s (or a 556). Both 555s in astable mode, first 555 lower frequency then the second 555. Drive the control voltage input of the second 555 from the "triangular" voltage waveform across the timing capacitor of the first 555.

There may be a need for a high impedance resistive potential divider between the capacitor and the control voltage input to limit the swing of the control voltage input.